# PHP - Issue formatting output from a loop

Tags: php, html, sql

A table looks like this:

```
user | score | 
hey     10         
SO      9
```

I have this script which loops through the table and outputs the username and score.

```
<?php 

if($result = $db->query("SELECT score,user FROM users ORDER BY score DESC ")){
    if($count = $result->num_rows){
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            echo $row->user, '<br><br>';
            echo $row->score, '<br><br>';
        }
        $result->free();
    }
}
?>
```

This gives output like so:

```
hey 
10

SO
9
```

Is it possible that I could have it like so:

```
#1 - hey: 10/10.
#2 - SO: 9/10.
```

I can't see how I can implement this while using the loop? My main gripe is the #1, #2, #3 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on it, let me know if it works.

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
if($result = $db->query("SELECT score,user FROM users ORDER BY score DESC ")){
    if($count = $result->num_rows){
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            echo "<p>#".$i." - ".$row->user." ".$row->score."/10</p><br>";
            $i++;
        }
        $result->free();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ah, a counter - perfect!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$counter = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo "#" . $counter++ . ' ';
    echo $row->user ' ';
    echo $row->score '<br><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build in a counter like this:

```
<?php 

if($result = $db->query("SELECT score,user FROM users ORDER BY score DESC ")){
if($count = $result->num_rows){
$counter=1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
       echo "#".$counter." - ".$row->user." ".$row->score."/10";
       $counter++;
       // echo $row->user, '<br><br>';
       // echo $row->score, '<br><br>';
    }
    $result->free();
}
}
?>
```